# How can you detect the fractional part of the player's y coordinate? [1.15]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My goal is to be able to detect if the fractional part of the player's y coordinate is within the ranges:

- .0 through .4
- .41 to 0.5
- .51 to 1

So for example, if the player is at y-value 64.375, this would fall under the .0 through .4 category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with only scoreboards and `/execute store`, without needing any dummy entities, teleportation, fancy pictures, etc., but using the fact that all entities (including players) store their coordinates in the `Pos` tag in NBT and that scoreboards use integer rounding (always down).

Firstly, two scoreboards are needed:

```
/scoreboard objectives add y dummy
/scoreboard objectives add y_10 dummy
```

Also, a standard in commands is to have a `const` scoreboard, so I'll put a 10 in there instead of one of the two existing ones:

```
/scoreboard objectives add const dummy
/scoreboard players set 10 const 10
```

Then you can just store your Y coordinate in the first two scoreboards, but one time multiplied with 10:

```
/execute store result score @s y run data get entity @s Pos[1]
/execute store result score @s y_10 run data get entity @s Pos[1] 10
```

Since scoreboards are integers, you would for example get `56` and `563` in them, if your Y position is 56.39154.

Now you can multiply the smaller one with 10:

```
/scoreboard players operation @s y *= 10 const
```

This would set your `y` score to 560 in my example.

Next, subtract the two:

```
/scoreboard players operation @s y_10 -= @s y
```

And there it is, the value `3` in the scoreboard `y_10`. You can for example do something depending on your wanted range of .0 to .4 like this:

```
/execute if score @s y_10 matches 0..3 run …
```

I set the upper limit to 3, because that 3 is a result of integer rounding, so the command would actually trigger if your Y coordinate's fractional part is between 0 and 0.399999….

Comment: This is a much better solution! Thank you, I will use this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually answering my own question, because I have found an answer.

---

First, I align entities to the bottom of the block the player is in, with `/execute align y` This makes sure the entities start at a whole number y value.

Then I position them a certain distance upwards, by teleporting them upwards. Example: `tp ~ ~0.2 ~` Now the entities are always at a y value of `21.2` or `64.2`, etc.

Finally, I use the `[distance=..<number>]` selector.

---

I created this 2D-side view diagram to help demonstrate:
[image]

In the diagram, the orange square represents the block that the player is standing in. The area_effect_clouds are represented by the black dots, and are at identical x and z coordinates of the player.

Lets say the player checks if they are anywhere from y=0 to y=0.4, with `execute if entity @e[tag=customTag,distance=..0.2]`

If the command returns true, we now know the player is within 0.2 blocks of that entity. This can be repeated for the other 3 sections.

Comment: Very nice answer, including the picture, well done. Also a creative idea, but I think my answer that I just posted would in practice be slightly preferable, because it has a smaller performance impact (but on a tiny scale, unless it's done very many times). Also, sometimes handling dummy entities is difficult, for example if two players get near each other, you might select the wrong AEC.